# Itemlabel font-size not applied in Jasper Report

Tags: charts, jasper-reports, label, ireport, jfreechart

I am creating a report with IReports version 3.7.5 (currently we use this version). In my report I have included a bar chart. I would like to show the label inside 'a bar'.

Currently this is done like this:
[image]

But now I want to modify the font-color and size, however this is not applied to my chart, and I could not find a bugreport for this?! Am I doing something wrong?

My JRXML part for this is:

```
<barPlot isShowLabels="true" isShowTickLabels="true" isShowTickMarks="true">
<plot>
    <seriesColor seriesOrder="0" color="#8FCB52"/>
    <seriesColor seriesOrder="1" color="#276FDD"/>
</plot>
<itemLabel color="#FF6600" backgroundColor="#33FF00">
    <font size="5"/>
</itemLabel>
<categoryAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA[$R{period}]]></categoryAxisLabelExpression>
<categoryAxisFormat>
    <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000">
        <labelFont>
            <font size="8"/>
        </labelFont>
        <tickLabelFont/>
    </axisFormat>
</categoryAxisFormat>
<valueAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA[$R{amount}]]></valueAxisLabelExpression>
<valueAxisFormat>
    <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" verticalTickLabels="false">
        <labelFont>
            <font size="8"/>
        </labelFont>
        <tickLabelFont/>
    </axisFormat>
</valueAxisFormat>
```

Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chart engine, JFreeChart, can do this. But iReport and JasperReports don't expose these font properties. You need a chart theme or a chart customizer.

You'll find more details on the jasperforge.org site. I wrote a [chart customizer tutorial](http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/2011/04/17/chart-customizers-2/) which could help.